# Angularjs orderBy in ng-repeat not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have the following div in my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in billing_history | orderBy:'-timestamp'">{{ item.date }}</div>
```

---

`console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.billing_history))` gives me the following:

```
{
  "May, 2015":{
     "date":"May, 2015",
     "timestamp":1432921230
  },
  "March, 2015":{
     "date":"March, 2015",
     "timestamp":1427846400
  },
  "February, 2015":{
     "date":"February, 2015",
     "timestamp":1425168000
  }
}
```

---

No matter what, this is what is displayed:

```
February, 2015
March, 2015
May, 2015
```

I've tried `orderBy:'-timestamp'` and `orderBy:'+timestamp'`

I'm really not sure why this isn't working. Does anyone see anything that could be going wrong?

Comment: it is not an array but what you have is object, i guess it wont work...

Comment: Any recommendations on what I need to do to get it to work? @PSL

Comment: Yes added an answer with a demo.. check it out... You would need to set up the view model as an array. Do you think you can do that?

Comment: Yea, I'll work on it. Thanks @PSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `order-by` filter with an object literal (or it wont just work as expected). What you have is an object literal basically there is no specific guaranteed ordering for the keys (and so for its values). You would need to convert it to an array.

Example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.billing_history = [{
    "date": "May, 2015",
    "timestamp": 1432921230
  }, {
    "date": "March, 2015",
    "timestamp": 1427846400
  }, {
    "date": "February, 2015",
    "timestamp": 1425168000
  }]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <p>Reverse order:
  <div ng-repeat="item in billing_history | orderBy:'-timestamp'">{{ item.date }}</div>
  <p>Correct order:
  <div ng-repeat="item in billing_history | orderBy:'timestamp'">{{ item.date }}</div>
</div>
```

Filter is one option, but be careful, filters are very performance intensive (they run as many times every digest cycle to stabilize and so what is in the filter matters much) and for operations like this on a large object it is very tricky. So better to set up view model appropriately or convert the format in the controller itself.

Answer (score 2):

`orderBy` filter works on an array and you are using it on a object. Convert the object into array and try it.

Demo 
http://plnkr.co/edit/4XtrJQaJ1itrVbb9bwE7?p=preview

Comment: Doesn't change. I tried `orderBy: timestamp : reverse` and `orderBy: timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom filter as Justin Klemm does [here](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/)

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

And then your markup turns into:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in billing_history | orderObjectBy:'timestamp'">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

Or

```
<div ng-repeat="item in billing_history | orderObjectBy:'-timestamp'">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

See this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/borivihisi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Nice one!! But filters are very performance intensive, especially for operations like this better to do the conversion on the controller rather than using filters on DOM. Also there is already a built in order filter so no need to really reinvent it IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for the workaround Tom. But it was a quick fix to get them to be arrays.